# Multiple foreign key referencing same attribute

Tags: sql-server

If a table has multiple foreign keys which reference same attribute of another table, how should be it written?

**foreign key(A,B) references table_name(C)**

or,

**foreign key(A,B) references table_name(C,C)**

here, A,B,C are attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is written as *two* foreign key references:

```
foreign key (A) references table_name(C),
foreign key (B) references table_name(C),
```

That is, each foreign key reference is defined using its own clause.

Answer (score 0):

No you should create two foreign keys referencing the same primary key.
As follows:

**foreign key(A) references table_name(C)**

**foreign key(B) references table_name(C)**